# masterdetail page in all App (xamarin)

Tags: xamarin, master-detail

I'm developing a new app in `xamarin` forms, with `xaml/c#` (android). I create a masterdetailpage for my `mainpage.xaml`. In `mainpage.xaml` I've a button that I use to navigate to `page2.xaml`.

The problem is that when I navigate to `page2.xaml` the menu of masterdetailpage does not display in `page2.xaml`. Why?

In `app.cs` I use this:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MenuPage());
```

and for navigate to `page2.xaml` I use this:

```
private async void NavigateButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await  Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2.xaml());
}
```

my solution is this https://1drv.ms/u/s!Au38Bd03gO0OltdpwWECrjjsOFTjYA

Comment: You should not put your master page inside navigation page.Each Details page can be navigation page.

Comment: I changed the MasterDetailPage.Detail with this '    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
            <local:Detail></local:Detail>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>' and if i navigate to page2.xaml it works good and show the menu in the page2.xaml and i can go back to the MainPage.but there is another problem: if i insert a button tu the masterdetailpage.detail for navigate to the page2.xaml it go to page2.xaml but i can't see the menu page.. why?

Comment: can you edit your question code, not comments? it is more clear there

Comment: ok , i've uploaded my solution. you can see that if i go to page2 (now called argomenti.xaml) from the button of the detail page i can see argomenti.xaml with the menu and i can go back. if i go to argomenti.xaml from the menu, so from the master, i can't se the menu in argomenti but i am able to go back

Comment: Sorry, working on another question right now :-) I will take a look and post if I can help

Comment: I already told you - you cannot put your MenuPage (which is MasterPage) inside Navigation page. Instead of MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MenuPage()); you should do new MenuPage(); BUT now you cannot do Navigation.PushAsync(new Argomenti()); because you don't have Navigation. You have to pick either use Navigation without MasterPage OR MasterPage with Navigation ONLY between details pages not going all the way up

Comment: My personal preference is to use Navigation. If you use MasterPage you really should read docs how it suppose to work.

Comment: oh...i'm sad for this but ok, now i understand...for now...i belive to use masterpage inside navigation page. in this way i've the menu in all pages of my app and i can navigate perfectly. for the menu, i can use it only for other pages that not require other menu (like info page, contact page, setting page, etc)... if you think about other solutions contact me please. thanks for all

Comment: the "EXTREME" solution is to re-create all pages and change it from ContentPage in MasterDetailPage and copy and past the same master in all pages and copy the last content page of each pages in the detail of each pages...it's hard to understand but it is the only way to do this...I hope.... there is only a little thing..in this way the menu when is open, stay above the title bar and not under.... Thanks for all, really

Comment: My suggestion is to forget about MasterPage. Use Navigation and you will be fine

Comment: oleeee!! i'm really happy I found the solution!!

Answer (score 0):

the solution is this!! the cs code of button activity in menu page is this: `        private void Button1_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

```
     ChangeDetail(new Argomenti());
```

}

private void ChangeDetail(Page page)

{

var navigationPage = Detail as NavigationPage;

if (navigationPage != null)

{

navigationPage.PushAsync(page);

return;

}

Detail = new NavigationPage(page);

}
` in this way i can go to another page (in this case Argomenti.xaml), i was able to see the menupage and i was able also to go back!!! it's fantastic! I want to share with you this solution. in internet is difficult to found a complete solution! Now there is the solution!

Answer (score 0):

This works well if you're using MVVM and dependency injection.

We did this by creating a navigation service class as a Singleton which wraps the Navigation of Xamarin (we found this to be a good idea since it allowed us to write Unit tests around Navigation).

```
public class NavigationService : INavigationService
{       
    private NavigationPage _navigationPage;
    private MasterDetailPage _masterPage;

    public NavigationService()
    {            
    }

    public void RegisterNavigationPage(NavigationPage navigationPage)
    {
        _navigationPage = navigationPage;
    }

    public void RegisterMasterPage(MasterDetailPage masterPage)
    {
        _masterPage = masterPage;
    }        


    public void NavigateTo(Page page)
    {
        _navigationPage = new NavigationPage(page);   
        _masterPage.Detail = _navigationPage;          
    }
}
```

You can extend this further to include PushAsync, PopAsync etc etc.

On app start up you set up the pages like:

```
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();    

        var masterPage = new MasterDetailPage();
        var navPage = new MyPage1();
        masterPage.Master = menuPage;
        masterPage.Detail = navPage;

        InitialiseNavigationService(navPage, masterPage);
        MainPage = masterPage;         
    }

    private void InitialiseNavigationService(NavigationPage navPage, MasterDetailPage masterPage)
    {

        var navigationService = Container.Get<INavigationService>();
        navigationService.RegisterNavigationPage(navPage);
        navigationService.RegisterMasterPage(masterPage);
    }
```

You can then simply call the navigation service to 'replace' the Detail page by

```
    _navigationService.NavigateTo(new MyPage2());
```